# Merge Search and Filter Rails 3 and Meta_Search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, merge, filter, meta-search

I have this code:

```
    <div id="busca">
    <div id="form_busca">
        <%= form_for @search, :url => root_path, :html => {:method => :get} do |f| %>
            <%= f.text_field :bairro_or_cidade_or_logradouro_or_estado_contains ,:id => "campo_busca", :placeholder => "Pesquise por logradouro, bairro ou cidade" %>
            <%= f.submit "Buscar", :id => "btn_busca" %>            
    </div>
</div>
        <div id="filtros">
                <ul>
                    <li><%= link_to "Some Text", root_path(:search => {:quartos_less_than => 2}) %></li>
                    <li><%= link_to "Some Text2", params.merge(:search => {:quartos_less_than => 2}) %></li>
                    <li><%= link_to "1 quarto", root_path(params.merge(:search => params[:search], :filter => {:quartos_less_than => 2})) %></li>
                    <li><%= link_to "+ de 1 quarto", params.merge(:search => params[:search], :filter => {:quartos_greater_than => 2}) %></li>
                    <li><%= link_to "1 banheiro", params.merge(:search => params[:search], :filter => {:banheiros_less_than => 2}) %></li>
                    <li><%= link_to "+ de 1 banheiro", params.merge(:search => params[:search], :filter => {:banheiros_greater_than => 2}) %></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        <a id="filtros_link" href="#">Filtros &raquo;</a>
<% end %>
```

I'd like to merge this links from **filtros** (filters) to a previous search. For exemple:
I search for a city then I filter this search to show those that have 1 bathroom only.

Can someone helpe me?

**I'm using ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 3.0.4. The search gem is meta_search.**

I thank you from now!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the best way I got is to use different parameters instead of only :search.
So, I'd use, for example, use the params :rooms :baths or any other not to merge, but to filter (let say this way).
The controller must be change as well. Then, using :rooms and :baths params in view, controller should be something like this:

```
@search = Property.search(params[:search][:rooms][:baths])
```

Didn't test this!

I've change this to checks which meta_search has helpers for this.